# Проектирование Базы Данных. ER - модели

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, er-diagram

Посоветовали книгу "Гектор Гарсиа-Молина, Джеффри Ульман - Системы Базы Данных". В конце каждой главы есть упражнения. В книге сказано, что на их сайте есть решения, но не все. Помогите с одним из них.

Задача такая.

Представьте в виде ER-диаграммы структуру "футбольной" базы 
данных, охватывающей информацию о командах, об игроках и о 
болельщиках, включая следующие атрибуты:

1. для каждой команды - название, перечень имен игроков, имя капитана(из числа игроков), цвет формы;
2. для каждого игрока - имя;
3. для каждого болельщика - имя, название команды, имя любимого игрока и предпочитаемый цвет.

Не забывайте, что множество не является допустимым типом атрибута. Как обойти это ограничение при описании цветов формы команды?

Вот то что я смог начертить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправьте пожалуйста мною спроектированный ER-проект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Не забывайте, что множество не является допустимым типом атрибута. Как обойти это ограничение при описании цветов формы команды?*

Это ограничение обходится через отношение многие-ко-многим. В данном случае примером может быть `players_to_team`, `team_to_color`, `fan_to_color`
[image: Вот что у меня получилось]